# Trying to join items in a list in python

Tags: python, list, join

Oddly this isn't working. I have a list and I am trying to join each work together into one variable. Everything I have tried with `join` doesn't work right and spits out some weird garbage. Where am I making this blunder?

```
street = ['20', 'mi', 'west', 'of']
#I've tried 
#street = ''.join(street)
#street = ' '.join(street)
#I need the output to be
#street = '20 mi west of'
```

Comment: That looks right already.

Comment: `street = ' '.join(street)` is correct

Comment: The parentheses are completely redundant and would be removed by the interpreter.

Comment: Here is what I am getting with that code that was just deleted.. `[ ' 2 0 ' ,   ' m i ' ,   ' w e s t ' ,   ' o f ' ]`

Comment: Can you elaborate on why none of these are working for you?

Comment: Because when I try those, I am getting a list of strings. I need street to be one variable that is `street = '20 mi west of'`

Comment: python 3.7 is what I am using

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ReliableSneakyTrees demonstrates it

Comment: Are you running the `join` function twice? Once on the list and again on the result string. Make sure you only call it once or save to a new variable name.

Comment: @101 no you can run it over and over and it still produces `20 mi west of`

Comment: >>> street 
'20 mi west of'
>>> street = ''.join(street)
>>> street
'20 mi west of'
>>> street = ''.join(street)
>>> street
'20 mi west of'

Comment: No I’m not running it twice. When I take that string, I don’t even use join and I’m getting a list. When I run the join then I get some funky stuff that comes out.

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish can you post what is being outputted?

Comment: I just left but I can later this evening.

Comment: @GregM check my answer below where someone posted an answer .

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please clarify via (integrated) edits, not comments. Tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the same in CPython 2.7, 3.7, and 3.8 (on Windows, but this should not matter.

```
>>> ' '.join(['20', 'mi', 'west', 'of'])
'20 mi west of'
```

If you get anything different, copy and paste and give details as to which Python you are using on what system.

EDIT: What N Chauhan is suggesting is that you are doing the equivalent of

```
>>> ' '.join("['20','mi','west','of']")
"[ ' 2 0 ' , ' m i ' , ' w e s t ' , ' o f ' ]"
```

Comment: I am using a mac and when I join `street = ' '.join(street)` I am getting `[ ' 2 0 ' ,   ' m i ' ,   ' w e s t ' ,   ' o f ' ]` Notice how it adds the spaces .

Comment: It looks like it keeps spitting out elements of a list and not combining them into one  new element

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish what does `type(' '.join(street))` say?

Comment: It adds spaces between each character

Comment: I think your 'list' is actually a string that has a syntax that looks like a list. When you defined the list, make sure it isn't in any quotes

Comment: @NChauhan I edited my response to include your suggestion.